# How to use multiple Generic constraints for List and dictionary for a type?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

I want to create a generic method with two generic type parameters that parameters must be a List of objects or dictionaries but the C Sharp compiler won't allow that How can I achieve that scenario?

```
 public class GenericTest
    {
        public void GenericMethod<TSucess, TFailed>(TSucess success, TFailed failure) 
            where TSucess : List<BatchResponseProperties>, Dictionary<string, string>, new()
            where TFailed : List<BatchInput>, Dictionary<string, string>, new()
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: C# doesn't support union types. I expect you'll want a separate method for each.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar Is that any way to do using the same method?

Comment: There's no such thing as "or" in generic constraints, so any way that you do it would lose type safety at the point of calling the method. You could use pattern matching inside (e.g;. `if (success if X) else if (success is Y)`) but then you could end up with unexpected types being passed in.

Comment: Even if you were allowed this constraint, I'd be surprised if you could actually write a single implementation that would work correctly against both types, without in fact having to perform type checks within the method and effectively splitting the implementation into a "works with list" half and a "works with dictionary" half - at which point you're really writing two methods in disguise.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar what if I create class model that contains both constraint and apply using null check

Comment: Just overload the method. It doesn't work the way you want it to. How would you write code inside the method that would work for both a list and a dictionary without using `if` statements anyway, which would completely defeat the purpose of a generic method.

Comment: You mean like using the `OneOf` NuGet package to pass a variable that's "one of" `List<BatchResponseProperties>` or `Dictionary<string, string>`? That's still basically creating two methods in disguise as Damien said.

Comment: Yes correct, instead of creating a generic method creating Method overload is the best idea to solve my problem, thanx